# Can ordered sets have repeats?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In class, we learned the sets $$\{1\}=\{1,1\}.$$
For a basis of a vector space (we learned that these are ordered sets), you can't have a repeat by definition (linearly independent). However, for coordinate vectors, an ordered set, you can have repeats. What gives? Are these "true" sets?

Comment: It is called a tuple, which is not a set.

Comment: Are basis also a tuple @eti902 ?

Comment: A basis would be a set of tuples.

Comment: I understand. So when my professor said "the coordinate vector with respect to $B$ of $v = \sum c_i v_i$ is defined as the ordered set $[v]_B := \{ c_1, ..., c_k \}$" is this incorrect?

Comment: I would personnally not choose this terminology, as it is very misleading.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, as I was mislead. I think I understand it better now. So are vectors tuples then?

Comment: Ordered bases are ordered *lists* of vectors. Two ordered lists are equal if they have the same length, and for each $i$ less than or equal to their common length, the $i$th element in the first list is equal to the $i$th element of the second list. Coordinate vectors are taken relative to ordered bases, and not merely bases (linearly independent spanning sets).

Comment: there is a distinction between a set and a tuple. in the former, order does not matter. in the latter, order does matter. an "ordered set" is a tuple

Comment: Let me add that the conventional meaning of "ordered set" is a set equipped with an order relation of some kind. In particular, it is a set.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy In the context of lunear algebra, especially beginning linear algebra, "tuples" often refers to specific types of vectors in standard spaces, or to coordinate vectors. As such, using the same tetm to refer to ordered lists of vectors (tuples of tuples) is probably not the most clarifying idea.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin an ordered list of objects, any objects, whether they are vectors or apples, is a tuple by definition

Comment: When I learned about bases, we learned that bases must be an ordered set. So that is also incorrect, they are an ordered list? And there is a distinction between ordered and unordered bases @ArturoMagidin?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy (i) That is one way to define it. (ii) I am well aware of it. (iii) I explicitly said the concern lies in potential confusion to beginners, not in a problem with what things are.

Comment: It's a matter of convention and context, not an issue of "correct" or "incorrect". Yes, there is a difference between having an ordered list and having a set. You cannot define coordinate vectors unless your basis has some kind of ordering attached.

Comment: Right. For what you're saying about tuples, couldn't an ordered set not have repeats but a tuple could? For bases, are bases not implicitly "ordered" -- as we learned in class, they are an "ordered set".

Comment: @user129393192 a basis of a vector space is not an ordered set. it often convenient to assign some arbitrary order to the basis vectors (e.g. when conducting a proof), but by definition a basis is a linearly independent subset of the vector space containing as many vectors as possible. it is set.

Comment: I see. The definition in class mentioned a basis has to be "ordered", to be used for any practical purpose it seems like it does.

Comment: @user129393192 sure, you can order the basis vectors for some practical purpose as long as you recall that the basis is actually just a set. if you don't, then you might mistakenly conclude that $\{ (0,1), (1,0) \}$ and $\{ (1,0), (0,1) \}$ are two distinct bases of the Cartesian plane, when in fact they are not.

Comment: But aren't they distinct bases? For example, the change of coordinate matrix $[id_v]_B^R$ where B and R are the bases would not be the identity matrix.

Comment: no they are the same basis

Comment: @user129393192 - Hmm, you've made a good observation that I hadn't realized before. While a basis is just a set, when we want to write the matrix of a linear transformation we do it with respect to a specific ordering of that set. Very cool to notice that.

Comment: There's this phenomenon that I've seen before, where, if we want to refer to the individual elements of a finite set, we have to write them down one after the other, so that does implicitly put an order on them, and we often don't notice. We just have to pay attention and remember that ordering doesn't matter when deciding if two sets are equal.

Answer (score 0):

An "ordered set" sometimes called a multi-set/tuple is really a set of ordered pairs, where the first coordinate is a natural number and second coordinate is the set being ordered.

So, the set {(0,a),(1,b)....(26,z)} produces a so called "multi-set". Which, is indeed a set.

As a matter of notation you'll sometimes see <...> to indicate an ordered tuple/multi-set/sequence

So we have <a,b,c,...,z> as an ordered set, multiset, or tuple. Alternatively, it's a sequence or encoding

So a "repeat" in a ordered set isn't a true repeat. Consider <x,x>. Since one element would really be the ordered pair (0,x) and the other would be (1,x)

Note: You could create tuples with other orderings besides the natural one on the natural numbers.